# undefined method `stringify_keys' for Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am fairly new to the world of Ruby and Rails (started a week ago, my background is mostly PHP). I've got this class here which acts as a factory.

I get the following error :

**undefined method `stringify_keys' for #**

I understand the constructor  (.new) expects a Hash instead of an object (why ?) but, although I spent a couple of hours searching the www, I didn't come up with a viable solution at this point.

I just want to inject that Soap object into my constructor. That constructor is pretty straightforward, it puts the object parameter in the instance variable that is supposed to store it.
I've been looking for methods that would turn that object into a proper Hash but all I saw was a bunch of OLD posts with rather dirty hacks. I'd rather quit programming than use them ^^.

I never thought doing this would cause a headache...

Thanks for the tips !

```html
class WebServices::WebServiceFactory
  def initialize (type, url, login, password, protocol = "soap")
    @type, @protocol, @url, @login, @password = type, protocol, url, login, password
    case @protocol.capitalize
    when "Soap" then
      requestor = WebServices::Soap::Soap.new(url, login, password)
    end

    @class = @type.constantize.new(requestor)
  end
  
  def getservice
    return @class
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `initialize` method can accept whatever arguments you define, it doesn't need to be a Hash, and in fact, the code above it looks like you have 5 arguments that can be of any type.

Are you wanting to pass the `Soap` object as an argument of `initialize`?

If you are, something like this would do (assuming you are using your version of Ruby is >= 2.0)

```
class WebServices::WebServiceFactory
  def initialize(requestor:, type:)
    @class = type.constantize.new(requestor)
  end
end
```

If you want this class to handle the details of creating the `Soap` object, maybe something like this would work for you:

```
module WebServices
  class WebServiceFactory
    SERVICES = {
      soap: 'WebServices::Soap::Soap'
    }

    def initialize(type:, protocol: :soap, params: {})
      return unless SERVICES.key?(protocol.to_sym)
      requestor = SERVICES[protocol.to_sym].constantize.new(params[:url], params[:login], params[:password])
      @class = type.constantize.new(requestor)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, the second option looks great and more like what I wanted to achieve in the first place, my version is ruby 2.0.0p247 and I think some of the syntax above won't make it or so it looks like on NetBeans, but I'll try with the appropriate syntax and tell you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the same error here : "undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<WebServices::Soap::Soap:0xb5da5c4>". Something's wrong with @class = type.constantize.new(requestor) but I can't really see what/why...